# LibreOffice doesn't have an icon

Tags: macos, icon

In the application menu LibreOffice has no icon. How can I add it to it?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: "doesn't has a *distinctive* icon"? So that you would like to add one that would suit you better?

Comment: FWIW, I've notified LibreOffice Design team about this issue: https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/design/msg08865.html .

Comment: Good UX feedback. Send this thread to them. ;)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The Icon shown *is* the LibreOffice icon.

Answer (score 70):

What you are seeing was in fact the correct icon for the LibreOffice suite.

To make it explicit, here's the full set of the application icons of the LibreOffice suite, together with the LibreOffice icon itself on top (image taken from [their website](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/File:LibreOffice_icons_256.png)):

[image: all application icons from LibreOffice]

Notice how the top icon, the LibreOffice general icon, is the same "empty document" icon as you have on your desktop. And here's the logo from [their web page](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/File:LibreOffice_Initial-Artwork-Logo_ColorLogoBasic_500px.png):

[image: The Document Foundation logo]

From version 7.5 on, the main icon is redesigned to be more in line with iOS and macOS icons, hopefully reducing confusion:[image: Icons from version 7.5]

Comment: What I'd expect is that they show the right icon depending on the active application - Writer, Calc, Express, etc. like it's done in Microsoft Office. Instead they show this "new file" icon, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to change the icon anyway, you can change the icon of any app in one of two ways (although there may be more ways to do this):

**Manually**

1. Find an app in the Finder, usually in your `/Applications/` folder.
2. Click on it and press <kbd>⌘I</kbd> to bring up the Information panel
3. Drag the icon file you want to use onto the application's current icon on the top left.

Note: step 3 will only work if you have an `.icns` file. If you have a `.png` file (most common) which you would like to use as your application's icon, perform the following steps:

1. Open the image you want to use with Preview
2. Press <kbd>⌘A</kbd> to "select all" of the image in Preview
3. Press <kbd>⌘C</kbd> to copy the image
4. Go back to the information panel and click on the application's current icon on the top left
5. Press <kbd>⌘V</kbd> to paste the image.

If you would like to restore the application's original icon, simply click on the application's icon in the Info panel and press <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd>. This will remove the custom icon.

**Using a Program**

If you want to do this for many applications, or you need to do this relatively often for a program which keeps on resetting its icon due to frequent updates or any other reason, you can save a lot of time using a free, lightweight tool called [LiteIcon](https://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/).

As with the manual method, to restore any application's original icon, simply click on the application's icon in the Info panel and press <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd>. Alternatively you can go into LiteIcon and drag a custom icon "off" an app, which will also restore the original icon.

Answer (score 0):

I concur; the generic document icon for LibreOffice on macOS is confusing to see in the Dock. What I have done is replace it with this distinctive icon. Hope this helps.  https://iconarchive.com/show/red-orb-alphabet-icons-by-iconarchive/Letter-L-icon.html